# DateFormat adding yy-mm-dd to DateTime when I specifically called for hh:mm

Tags: flutter, datetime

The code is as follows:

```
DateTime time = DateFormat("hh:mm").parse(doc[i]["Time"]);
```

The doc[i]["Time"] value is supposed to be a military time like 19:42. I followed the guidelines about using DateFormat but the end result variable time contains "1970-01-01 19:42:00.000". Is there a way for time to just contain "19.42"?

Comment: would you please add what `doc` is ?

Comment: It is simply a json file I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

A `DateTime` type will always store everything including year, month, hour, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, etc.

But when you later use the variable, you can chose what to display.

For example, you can chose to display just the military time. Here is one example using the Intl package ([here](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install))

```
Text(DateFormat('Hm').format(yourVariable))
```

Don't forget to import

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Comment: Is it possible to display the formatted resulted in a DateTime variable instead of a String.

Comment: No , you can't control the format in DateTime. Just format the resulting string. Let me know about your usecase? you should not need that.

Answer (score 0):

To get time in 24hrs format change your code to

```
String time = DateFormat("HH:mm").format(doc[i]["Time"]);
```

H -> is for 24 hours format

Comment: This would result in the right hand side being a DateTime type assigned to a string. I want the resulting variable to be a DateTime of format "HH:mm".

Comment: using DateTime it will show date and will lead you to same problem. Instead we use TimeOfDay class to show only time. Still I feel String should work as it works in most of the cases. If you can share your code, it will be easy to suggest best way to go around.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use DateTime to show a specific format, must always become a String.